# Is there a way to get IAP receipt from iTunes Account?

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, subscriptions, auto-renewing

One of my app is running well on Apple Appstore also generating revenues. In that app user has to pay through `Auto-Renewable Subscription` for registration. On 13th May (Day before yesterday) a user tried to create his account but after the payment was done, my server could not saved IAP Receipt. It might happen through internet connectivity issue with the device. The App flow is:

1. Put values for registration like name, surname, email, pwd
2. Press register button
3. In app purchase starts
4. Payment is done
5. Get receipt from apple.
6. Save receipt on my server db along with his login details

So in the case that failed, the process could not reach 5th and 6th step and I could not get payment receipt. Also there in no registration details are there on my server db.

After verifying the payment, I gave him access to use the app by creating his account manually. But still I want the payment receipt so that i can further check his subscription is active or not.

Is it possible to get payment receipt now? Even in `NSData` form? My I tunes account is having anything related to this?

Comment: What iOS system does your user have? With iOS7, you could use SKReceiptRefreshRequest.

Comment: that what i can not get in my current app version in appstore. I am tracking `iOS` version in next sub version of the app, to be released. But thanks for `registerNewUser`, i will try to understand this term and will include in my next drop.